# Get the size of a directory recursively - C

Tags: c, recursion, directory, size

I'm trying to get the size of a directory recursively but I only get segfaults. I really can't see where I'm wrong, could someone help me?
P.S. I don't need to verify if the file exist or not, this is only a try for another function I have to write.

Here's the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  printf("%d\n", size(argv[1]));
  return 0;
}

int is_folder(char * path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;
    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return !(S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode));
}

int size(char * name)
{
  int dir_size = 0;
  struct dirent * pDirent;
  DIR * pDir = opendir(name);
  while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
  {
    char buf[PATH_MAX + 1];
    realpath(pDirent->d_name, buf);
    if (is_folder(buf))
    {
      size(buf);
    }
    else
    {
      struct stat st;
      stat(buf, &st);
      int sz = st.st_size;
      dir_size += sz;
    }
  }
   return dir_size;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger to identify the line causing the segfaults?

Comment: Seeing as we don't know how you run the program, the very first line of `main` should be `if(argc < 2) exit(1);`. Similarly you omit to check the return value from `stat` and `realpath`.

Comment: The debugger says this: 0x00007ffff7ad2fe6 in readdir64 () from /lib64/libc.so.6

Comment: Okay I got it: the debugger says the problem is in size(buf) --> the recursion. It seems that buf has 0 value, that's the NULL value. But why? The while statement should have excluded this situation.

Comment: You need to concatenate the directory name with `d_name` to get the full path to the file. `realpath()` won't do it.

Comment: If you checked for errors from `stat()`, you would have seen that it's reporting "No such file or directory".

Comment: Yes, it was reporting NULL value. So you say: if my directory is "foo" and a sub-dir is "bar', what i'm trying to open is "foobar" and i need to add the '/' ? @Barmar

Comment: You're trying to open `bar`, you're not adding `foo` at all. It should be `foo/bar`.

Comment: BTW, you don't need to call `realpath()`. All the system calls that operate on files will take relative paths.

Comment: Thanks very much man @Barmar

Comment: Also, you're not using the result of the recursion. You need `dir_size += size(buf);`.

Comment: Okay I just fixed that but: to try I'm measuring the size of the linux source. If I do "du -h linux-src" i get 735MB, the correct value. But with "ls -lh" and also my tool I get only 665KB. I mean, not only my tool is wrong but also ls. That's strange @Barmar

Answer (score 0):

Building on your code, below is the closest I was able to reproduce what `du -sk` returns:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <string.h>

off_t directorySize(char *directory_name)
{
    off_t directory_size = 0;

    DIR *pDir;

    if ((pDir = opendir(directory_name)) != NULL)
    {
        struct dirent *pDirent;

        while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)) != NULL)
        {
            char buffer[PATH_MAX + 1];

            strcat(strcat(strcpy(buffer, directory_name), "/"), pDirent->d_name);

            struct stat file_stat;

            if (stat(buffer, &file_stat) == 0)
            {
                directory_size += file_stat.st_blocks * S_BLKSIZE;
            }

            if (pDirent->d_type == DT_DIR)
            {
                if (strcmp(pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0 && strcmp(pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0)
                {
                    directory_size += directorySize(buffer);
                }
            }
        }

        (void) closedir(pDir);
    }

    return directory_size;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    printf("%lldKiB\n", directorySize(argv[1]) / 1024);

    return 0;
}
```

I'm guessing the difference you're seeing is due to directories consuming a small amount of space which you need to include in your total and that file space usage is chunked so you need to count blocks, not bytes.

Comment: This answer opened my mind. THANK. YOU. I don't know why but I tried your algorithm on the linux source and returned only 660KB... so I mixed up mine and yours and I get quite the same results of du -sh. I'm posting that down here.

Answer (score 0):

After one night spent on trying how to find a size that is quiet the same of the one reported by du -sh: I wrote this and it seems to work also on large directories (like the linux source that is 750MB or more).

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <dirent.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>

long folder_size(char *);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
  if (argc < 2)
  {
    exit(1);
  }
  printf("%ld\n", mysize(argv[1]));
  return 0;
}

int not_folder(char * path)
{
    struct stat path_stat;
    stat(path, &path_stat);
    return (S_ISREG(path_stat.st_mode));
}

long folder_size(char * name)
{
  long dir_size = 0L;
  struct dirent * pDirent;
  DIR * pDir = opendir(name);
  while ((pDirent = readdir(pDir)))
  {
    if (strcmp (pDirent->d_name, "..") != 0 && strcmp (pDirent->d_name, ".") != 0)
    {
      char buf[PATH_MAX];
      strcpy(buf, name);
      strcat(buf, "/");
      strcat(buf, pDirent->d_name);
      if (not_folder(buf))
      {
        struct stat st;
        stat(buf, &st);
        dir_size += st.st_blocks * S_BLKSIZE;
        printf("%s %ld\n", buf, (long)st.st_size);
      }
      else
      {
        dir_size += folder_size(buf);
      }
    }
  }
  (void) closedir(pDir);
  return dir_size;
}
```

Comment: 1) code does not check the return value of `stat()`.  2) `st.st_blocks * S_BLKSIZE` may overflow.  3) `dir_size += st.st_blocks * S_BLKSIZE;` may overflow.  Better to use `unsigned long long`. 4) No need to repetitively call `char buf[PATH_MAX]; strcpy(buf, name); strcat(buf, "/");` Just run that once before the while loop, record its length and then do `strcpy(buf + len, pDirent->d_name);`